# How to access Jolokia server on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, jolokia

I deployed application on Google Compute Engine. My VM has an internal IP and an external IP.

I am running my application with Jolokia:

```
java -javaagent:jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=host=0.0.0.0 -jar openmzn-processor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(internal IP):8778/jolokia
....
```

I loaded hawtio server and tried connecting jolokia server.

```
Connection Information on QHawtio Console.
- Name: XXXX
- Scheme: http
- Host: External IP
- Port: 8778
- Path: /jolokia
```

When I tested connection, howtio application cannot access to jolokia.

How can I access jolokia application from my hawtio console?

Comment: I resolved this issue.

Comment: glad to know it, could you share/describe the solution with the community,  there could be something useful for anyone else with the same issue :)

Comment: Also, to extend what @J.Rojas said — we're happy to hear that you've solved the problem; could you please post your solution as an answer and [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that (a) other folks know how to solve this issue, and (b) this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Comment: Hawtio console has two type connection that is remote and discovery.
Remote connection need to configure server information. In this case, I think that hawtio doesn't know internal ip address. Another connection is discovery. This connection find jolokia server automatically. First step, your interanl server information have to be identified through discovery function. And connection information by using discovery is shown on remote connection tab. Now, you can access your jolokia server.

Comment: Can you please move your solution from a comment into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hawtio console has two type connection that is remote and discovery. Remote connection need to configure server information. In this case, I think that hawtio doesn't know internal ip address. Another connection is discovery. This connection find jolokia server automatically. First step, your interanl server information have to be identified through discovery function. And connection information by using discovery is shown on remote connection tab.